# Including Class with .h and .cpp files

Tags: c++

I am trying to use a class in .ino file. The code is:
 
 .ino file

```
#include <LED.h>

int Pin1 = 13;
int Pin2 = 12;
int Pin3 = 11;
LED led;
void setup() {
  pinMode(Pin1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin3,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Pin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  led.on(Pin1);
  delay(2);
  led.on(Pin2);
  delay(2);
  led.on(Pin3);
  delay(2);
}
```

.h file

```
#ifndef LED_h
#define LED_h

class LED{
public:
    void on(int);
    void off(int);
};

#endif
```

.cpp file

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <Arduino.h>
#include "LED.h"    

void LED::on(int PIN){
    digitalWrite(PIN,HIGH);
}

void LED::off(int PIN){
    digitalWrite(PIN,LOW);
}
```

Arduino compiler picks the object declaration error:

LEDC:6: error: 'LED' does not name a type
LEDC.ino: In function 'void loop()':
LEDC:17: error: 'led' was not declared in this scope

How should I declare objects in Arduino then?

The way that I am putting the files in folders is like the attached image:

[image]

Comment: There is nothing syntactically wrong with your program - it compiles perfectly in UECIDE. My guess is it's something to do with the Arduino IDE.  Which version of the IDE are you using? I know that recently they have made some changes to how the compilation works (or maybe *doesn't* work).

Comment: It is Arduino 1.5.6

Comment: Your LED.cpp and LED.h files are in an LEDD subfolder. In your LEDC.ino file you should use `#include "LEDD/LED.h"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That version of the IDE (it seems to change from version to version) differentiates between includes with `<...>` and includes with `"..."`.

If you use `<...>` it only looks in the system and library areas.  If you use `"..."` it also looks inside your sketch.

So in your main INO file change the LED include from:

```
#include <LED.h>
```

To:

```
#include "LED.h"
```

and it should compile.

Comment: Still does not compile. Maybe the way that I am putting the files in folders is not right? See the image in main question.

Comment: I did it by adding two new tabs - LED.cpp and LED.h and pasting your code into them.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is this in the (.ino)

```
#include <LED.h>

int Pin1 = 13;
int Pin2 = 12;
int Pin3 = 11;
LED led1;
LED led2;
LED led3;
void setup() {
  pinMode(Pin1,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin2,OUTPUT);
  pinMode(Pin3,OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(Pin1,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin2,LOW);
  digitalWrite(Pin3,LOW);
}

void loop() {
  led1.on(Pin1);
  delay(2);
  led2.on(Pin2);
  delay(2);
  led3.on(Pin3);
  delay(2);
}
```